# Is it Ok to connect mysql database to android without json?

Tags: java, android, json

i have been trying to connect mysql db with android app, and through json i cannot connect it, is it ok not to use json or use any method without json ?

Comment: thank you all for downgrading and not answering, i'm really honored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never needed JSON. You could use XML instead, or create your own serialized format.

The purpose of using a web API (assuming you are using PHP + MySQL) is that you should not use JDBC directly from the Android app

Comment: thanks man, can i get your website ,email or Facebook , i have a lots of question about android(java) that i can ask, i have a limit of one question per week here on stackoverflow, due to my low points, i you can help me i will be very grateful :)

Comment: Once you ask higher quality questions, then the site will allow you to post more often. You can go to the Help Center for more information. For example, instead of asking about JSON, you should ask about those "connection problems". Try to fix the current problem, not create a new one... Otherwise, you have an "XY Problem"

Comment: lol that would take years for me, now i can't ask question in 7 days and theres no other forum where i can ask question

Comment: sorry for bothering you , what are the new way to connect mysql to android, all the methods i saw on youtube are 3-4 years old and is deprecated now , can you help ?

Comment: Php is not deprecated... So, I don't know what you're looking at. You could ask questions on reddit androiddev site, maybe

Comment: httpclient is deprecated

Comment: Correct, but that has nothing to do with MySQL. Read the Android documentation online how to do network operations